# Application is not starting in tomcat with spring security

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to learn spring security concepts, In my console i'm not seeing any exceptions or any errors. but my application is not starting. I am not sure where i'm missing can anybody helps me.

I am using Spring4.x, tomcat7

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MTM</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-applicationContect.xml,/WEB-INF/security-applicationContect.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- MVC filter -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Spring filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**

> security-applicationContect.xml

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Global security settings -->
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- Form and security access config -->

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?time=1">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                expired-url="/login?time=1" />
        </session-management>
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login.do"
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?err=1"
            default-target-url="/login.jsp"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?out=1"
            invalidate-session="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole(ROLE_USER)"
            requires-channel="https" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="karna" password="paul" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
```

**console log**

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.auth.pistos.controller.IndexController.index()
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.auth.pistos.controller.LoginController.login()
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 30 14:35:00 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 30 14:35:00 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Validated configuration attributes
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Validated configuration attributes
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Validated configuration attributes
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3538 ms
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-2015"]
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-2009"]
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6785 ms
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvcDispatcher'
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvcDispatcher': initialization started
Oct 30, 2015 2:35:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvcDispatcher': initialization completed in 116 ms
```

login.jsp is my welcome-file in web.xml and its body is:

```
<body>
    <form action="<c:url value='/login.do'/>" id="form" method="post">
        Username : <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /> <br />
        Password : <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Browser is displaying like:

```
This program cannot display the webpage

Most likely causes:
•You are not connected to the Internet.
•The website is encountering problems.
•There might be a typing error in the address.

What you can try:

  Check your Internet connection. Try visiting another website to make sure you are connected.  

  Retype the address.  

  Go back to the previous page.
```

My mvc-applicationContect.xml is having less configurations only like,

```
<beans>
<context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.auth.pistos.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and my controllers are as simple as

```
package com.auth.pistos.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the log your app is up "INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvcDispatcher': initialization completed in 116 ms" Are you hitting the correct url? Make your log level to debug for further info.

Comment: when you hit the jsp what does the browser show?

Comment: Put the logs in the controller for the jsp & check your logs. Your server is up probably some problem with the resource mapping.

Comment: Sounds like you use IE. Use another browser to get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Used Chrome and IE, but no use. Can somebody helps me.